# How can I read lines from file and cut it pieces?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[EDIT]

I specified my question, maybe it has more information:

I have a file with lots of lines like "string1 string2 int1 int2", so a line contains two strings and two integers. I would like to read the file line by line and push those four datas into a vector of my struct( which has the same variable types and num ). My question is, how can I do this, because the >> operator won't work anyway. Nor the getline().

and the code:

```
void FromFile(string filename)
{
    ifstream stream;
    stream.open(filename);
    adatok adattemp;
    while(stream.good())
    {
        stream >> adattemp.agresszor >> adattemp.vedo >> adattemp.haborukezdete >> adattemp.haboruvege >> ws;
        cout << adattemp.agresszor;
        vektor.push_back(adattemp);
    }
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: When you say "string string int int", is each string just a single word, or are the strings wrapped in quotes?

Comment: I'd use the `std::vector`

Comment: yeah, it's two words and two numbers(4 digits/number).

Comment: You're still having trouble? You could try turn on exceptions for the stream so you can see any errors occuring: put "`stream.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);`" before opening the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each string is just a single word, this should work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct Entry {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    int i1;
    int i2;
};

std::vector<Entry> entries;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("yourfile");
    while (file.good()) {
        Entry entry;
        file >> entry.s1 >> entry.s2 >> entry.i1 >> entry.i2 >> std::ws;
        entries.push_back(entry);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: it's important to include `>> std::ws` at the end of reading each line. It eats up extra whitespace. Otherwise you'll end up with an extra junk entry at the end of the file.

EDIT: As Simple pointed out in the comments, if any errors occur while reading the file, the above code will store a junk entry at the end of the `vector`. This code will fix that by making sure there are no errors before storing the entry:

```
Entry entry;
while (file >> entry.s1 >> entry.s2 >> entry.i1 >> entry.i2 >> std::ws)
{
    entries.push_back(entry);
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct loop for reading input. It should be more like: `Entry entry; while (file >> entry.s1 >> entry.s2 >> entry.i1 >> entry.i2 >> std::ws) { entries.push_back(entry); }`

Comment: The code is correct. It's just a matter of style. An optimizing compiler should produce the same machine code for both forms.

Comment: No it's not correct. Your code will insert invalid data into the `vector`. It's not an optimisation issue.

Comment: It doesn't insert invalid data. And why would it? The only real difference between the two is that in your version the loop condition is implicitly `while (!file.fail())` whereas mine is `while (file.good())`. Other than that, the two are semantically equivalent, and result in the same behaviour.

Comment: They're completely different. Your code first checks if the stream still has content in it, then tries to read four things from it and then inserting them into the vector *without checking if the reads were successful*. Mine tries to read the four things, then checks if the stream is still valid after those reads, and if it is then inserts them.

Comment: Ah, I see. So long as the input file is well-formed, it will work. In the case you mentioned, I can see that it would insert a junk entry.

Comment: @NeverJr It actually reads word by word, skipping all white-space, including line endings. So it will work whether the entries start on new lines or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not know the file size, a vector would be more suited IMO.

```
while ( myFile >> string1 >> string2 >> myInt1 >> myInt2 ) {
  stringvec1.push_back( string1 );
  stringvec2.push_back( string2 );
  intvec1.push_back( myInt1 );
  intvec2.push_back( myInt2 );
}
```

EDIT:

If the 4 variables that you are reading correspond to a particular logically meaningful class, then you can have one vector of class/struct with all these 4 as members.

Something like:

```
struct myFileVariables {
  std:string m_string1;
  std:string m_string2;
  int m_myInt1;
  int m_myInt2;
  myFileVariables ( string string1, string string2, int myInt1, int myInt2 ) :
                        m_string1( string1 ), m_string2( string2 ), m_myInt1( myInt1 ), 
                        m_myInt2( myInt2 ) {}
};
```

And in your main function:

```
    while ( myFile >> string1 >> string2 >> myInt1 >> myInt2 ) {
      myFileVariables newEntry( string1, string2, myInt1, myInt2 );
      myVec.push_back( newEntry );
    }
```

Comment: And why not a vector of appropriately defined `struct`s?

Comment: What would be the size of the array?

Comment: I meant vector, of course. (But you can haz dynamic arrays without vector too, so it doesn't matter -- how do you think vectors do their magic?) - the emphasis is on "why not a struct"?

Comment: I have a struct with four variables( the two string and the ints), and I made a vector from this struct. And many thanks for the answer :)

Comment: And this loop take every single line and put the values into the vector( and how split it)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd overload `>>` and use `std::copy`

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
//...
struct Reader {

    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
    int int1;
    int int2;

    friend std::istream& operator << (std::istream& is, Reader &r)
    {
       return is >> r.str1 >> r.st2 >> r.int1 >> r.int2 ;

    }
};

std::vector<Reader> vec;
std::ifstream  fin("file_name");

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Reader>(fin),
          std::istream_iterator<Reader>(),
          std::back_inserter(vec)
          ) ;
```

This assumes all string and int are seperated by white space

You can also overload `>>` too to display content in similar fashion